# cmake set_property on SOURCE files with COMPILE_FLAGS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, cmake

I'm using CMake 2.8.1 (tried this on CMake 2.8.5 too). I'm using the Visual Studio generator for VS2008.  I would like to selectively apply compile flags on some some source files differently than for other files, and all of these files are going into the same static library (splitting the library into two different targets is not an option at this time). I cannot use `set_target_properties` in this case because the compile flags must be different.  However I discovered something quite odd. The following works (works being defined that I see the `/flubber` option show up in the `AdditionalOptions` fields in the .vcproj file CMake generates):

```
set_property(SOURCE file1.cpp file2.cpp
  PROPERTY COMPILE_FLAGS /flubber
  )
```

But this does not work:

```
set_property(SOURCE file1.cpp file2.cpp
  PROPERTY COMPILE_FLAGS /GR
  )
```

Why is CMake filtering out or ignoring the `/GR` option? Is that a CMake bug or intentional?

Now this question is a bit contrived given that, circa VS2005, the /GR option was defined to be on by default (gives RTTI), so I really don't have to specify it.  But that isn't the point because there are other flags that start with "/G" that are perfectly valid to want to specify on one source file, but not another, and in the same static library target.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio provides special option for `/GR` flag:

[image]

cmake knows that and transforms your `/GR` flag into that option. If you open your cmake-generated project file (.vcproj) with notepad, then you can see additional `RuntimeTypeInfo="TRUE"` attribute inside your file configuration:

`/flubber` flag added:

```
<Tool Name="VCCLCompilerTool" AdditionalOptions="/flubber" />
```

`/GR` flag added:

```
<Tool Name="VCCLCompilerTool" RuntimeTypeInfo="TRUE" />
```

Comment: That was quite helpful. Marked as answer.